# Print non contiguous columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print several non-contiguous columns on one sheet of paper. I am using the set print area in page layout. However it has created a page break after each column range. I have a macro that allows you to paste a range of data, and then it clears the data and prints the page. So hiding the columns isn't working. Can someone tell me how to print just the columns I need on one piece of paper. Here is the macro where I would like to include the printing code.

```
Sub cleardatanotformulas()
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
    On Error Resume Next
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you tried hiding the columns you don't need to print, print and finally unhide the columns?

Comment: When I tried hiding the columns then the data is not copied into the sheet. I want the data on the sheet just not the print out. That's why I wondered if I can have it executed in the macro. Is this possible? Sorry I am not an advanced Excel user.

Comment: Anne, it's really hard to me to understand what do you need, how you are trying to do and what is the real problem. Maybe other guys had the same problem because you have 12 views and no answer or comment.

Comment: Agree with @DavidG. Description and code are kind of different, but maybe because you are new. I suggest a non-vba solution. Add a 2nd page and set it up with formula references to just the columns of data you need printed, then set up print format as needed. This is like a presentation layer that feeds from data calculated elsewhere.

Comment: Excel doesn't allow you to make a smooth print range from non-contiguous ranges. You'll have to make a macro that copies your data into a temporary sheet, make the print range, print, then deletes the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new page to receive your selected columns for printing Like this code below. Mu non-contiguous columns are in MySourceSheet. You have to copy them in MytargetSheet and print it.

```
Sub CopyInAdjacentColumnsForPrinting()

    Sheets("MySourceSheet").Select
    Range("A:A,C:C,E:E").Select 'We select A, C and E columns for example,     you can specify your own columns
    Range("E1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("MyTargetSheet").Select ' This sheet is for receiving selected     columns in contiguous columns.
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste ' We copied selected columns in this sheet.
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: Can I specify a range in my macro to print specific columns?

Comment: If your range is contiguous, I will say you YES. You can specify your range (with contiguous columns) like this :
`Range("A1:E10").Select` in this we specify cells in the range that starts with cell A1 and ends with cell E10. You can specify your own cells.YES

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @Anne B, I cannot add my code in comment bloc, then I add a new answer :)
Based on the fact that you copied your non-contiguous columns in the sheet named MyTargetSeet (in this example).
You can use this.

```
Sub ZoneImp()
 Dim FirstCol As Integer, LastCol As Integer, FirstLin As Integer, FirstLin As Integer

 FirstCol = 1
 LastCol = 3
 FirstLin = 1
 LastLin = 6
 'Here I create my Area for printing
 Sheets("MyTargetSheet").PageSetup.PrintArea = Range(Cells(FirstLin, FirstCol), Cells(LastLin, LastCol)).Address
End Sub
```

Hope this can help!